# ¿Cómo detectar memory leaks en mi aplicación que utiliza OpenCV?

Tags: java, manejo-de-memoria

Quisiera saber como encontrar una fuga de memoria ya que estoy haciendo un programa el cual tiene una el cual quiero resolver, la memoria utilizada aumenta *muy rápidamente* y necesito resolver el problema.

El programa en que estoy trabajando es de detección por rostro desde webcam por OpenCv utilizando las librerías de Javacv 1.1 y JavaCPP.

```
private IplImage detectFace(IplImage image, CvScalar color) {

    int number = 3;

    IplImage imageGray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

    cvCvtColor(image, imageGray, CV_BGR2GRAY); 


    IplImage smallImg = IplImage.create(imageGray.width()/2, imageGray.height()/2, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    cvResize(imageGray, smallImg, CV_INTER_LINEAR);

    cvEqualizeHist(smallImg, smallImg);

    CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();

    if(faceDetector.isNull())
        faceDetector = new CvHaarClassifierCascade(cvLoad(dataBase+"\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"));

    CvSeq faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(smallImg, faceDetector, storage, 1.3, number, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING);

    cvClearMemStorage(storage);

    int total = faces.total();

    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        CvRect r = new CvRect(cvGetSeqElem(faces, i));

        cvRectangle(image, cvPoint( r.x()*2, r.y()*2 ),cvPoint( (r.x() + r.width())*2,(r.y() + r.height())*2 ), color, 2, CV_AA, 0);
    }

    return image;
}//end of face detection
```

El anterior metodo es donde se encuentra la fuga de memoria.

Comment: No es muy fácil crear un memory leak en Java, los candidatos usuales son Maps (insertar keys sin límite), apendear indefinidamente (en un loop) a un String, StringBilder, List, etc. Hay herramientas (siu usas eclipse: https://www.eclipse.org/mat/) pero no suelen ser muy fáciles de usar . Si el programa no es muy grande, puedes postearlo aquí, y quizás podamos orientarte.

Comment: Listo, el programa requiere librerías de opencv.

Comment: opino lo mismo que leonbloy, si se consume muy rápido la memoria después de alojar imagenes seguramente , necesitas cvReleaseImage().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo pronto, lo que adivino (no usé OPenCV) es que está faltando liberar la memoria del `IplImage`
:

```
IplImage smallImg = IplImage.create(imageGray.width()/2, imageGray.height()/2, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
```

Faltaría un 
:

```
  cvReleaseImage(smallImg);
```

Mirar también en el código que llama a este método, el que crea la imagen que se le pasa como argumento, debería también hacer el release cuando deje de usar la imagen.

Comment: listo, el memory leak disminuyo considerablemente aunque aun hay otra pequeña fuga por el mismo metodo

Answer (score 1):

Bien, la fuga se ha reducido considerablemente pero sigue habiendo una fuga que comienza siendo pequeña y con el paso del tiempo imcrementa la cantidad de memoria que aumenta por segundo, El metodo de capturar video por camara es el siguiente:

```
    public void camaraDeteccion(CvScalar color, int dispositivo){
    if( archivoDetector.exists() && archivoDetector.isFile() ){
    if( archivoDetector.getName().endsWith(".xml") ){
        //Ventana de webcam
        CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("Webcam");
            canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));

        //Contenedor de la imagen capturada a procesar para la deteccion
        IplImage imagenCaptura = null;    
        //Capturador de imagenes por camara, se inicializa null
        FrameGrabber capturador = null;
            //Al capturador se le asigna un dispositivo por donde capturar las imagenes(0 = dispositivo predeterminado)
            try{
            capturador = new VideoInputFrameGrabber(dispositivo);
            }catch(Exception e){ System.err.println("No se encontro el disposituvo \""+dispositivo+"\" para obtener el flujo de imagenes"); return;}

        //Convertidor de Frames a IplImage
        OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage converter = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();

        try{
            //Se comienza a capturar imagenes
            capturador.start();
            //Contenedor de captura
            Frame captura;

            //Si la ventana canvas esta abierta
        while(true){

            //se captura una imagen
            captura = capturador.grab();
            //se convierte el frame que contiene la imagen a IplImage
            imagenCaptura = converter.convert(captura);

            try{
                imagenCaptura = detectarRostro(imagenCaptura, color);
            }catch(Exception e){ System.err.println("error al detectar"); }


            if (imagenCaptura != null) 
                canvas.showImage(captura);

            }//Fin del ciclo de captura

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println("camaraDeteccion() - Error al tratar de iniciar");
            return;
        }

    }else
            System.err.println("El archivo debe de ser formato xml");
    }else
        System.err.println("El archivo detector \""+ archivoDetector.getAbsolutePath() +"\" no existe");
}//Fin de la deteccion por camara
```

En el metodo detectarRostro libere la memoria de los IplImage: *imageGray* y *smallImg*, No se si el aumento sea por la variable IplImage de su argumento el cual devuelve. Pero cuando quito el método detectarRostro del bucle el uso de memoria se queda estable. Entonces por allí sigue habiendo fuga

Ademas que la detección consume aproximadamente 30% del cpu, la toma de video igual aumenta la memoria de muy poco a poco en lapsos de tiempo.

Comment: La declaración `private IplImage detectFace(IplImage image, CvScalar color)` es confusa/peligrosa porque no queda claro si devuelve la misma imagen o una nueva. Parece que devuelve la misma, así que no veo por qué lo haces así, cambiala a void. Y al final del bucle estás haciendo el release de imagenCaptura ?

Comment: y fijate si el CvHaarClassifierCascade no tiene su release. En general, en  opencv, cada vez que instancies (con new o con algun factory method) un objeto "complejo", fijate si hay algun release metod

Comment: Pero como devolveria la imagen procesada del método detectar rostro siendo void, si hago release al final del bucle de la imagenCapturada me tira NullPointerException  NULL en el siguiente ciclo, devuelve la misma imagen con excepción de que se le agrega un rectángulo si se detecto un rostro, como liberó un CvHaarClassifierCascade?

Answer (score 0):

Para detectar fugas de memoria (*memory leaks*) tienes muchas herramientas a tu alcance pero requiere un proceso un poco más metódico. Por ejemplo echa un vistazo a este artículo:

https://www.toptal.com/java/hunting-memory-leaks-in-java

En él se mencionan varios consejos, entre ellos:

- Lee con detenimiento el mensaje de error si existe, porque da pistas sobre el problema.
- Activa la información de depuración para la recolección de basura utilizando el argumento `-verbosegc`.
- Estudia en profundidad cómo funciona la recolección de basura en Java para poder identificar mejor los posibles fallos.
- Utiliza herramientas como [Java VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/) que representan gráficamente el ciclo de vida de los objetos.

[image: Java VisualVM]

Con estos consejos podrás **detectar memory leaks en tu aplicación Java**, te servirán de forma genérica tanto si usas OpenCV como si no y no darás palos de ciego intentando ver dónde está el error.